# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Studyjios> above this StudyjiosList Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tMhA.png)
I get an error: 
Could not find the correct `Provider<Studyjios>` above this `StudyjiosList` Widget when I try to run my app in VSCode.

To fix, please:

- Ensure the `Provider<Studyjios>` is an ancestor to this `StudyjiosList` Widget
- Provide types to `Provider<Studyjios>`
- Provide types to `Consumer<Studyjios>`
- Provide types to `Provider.of<Studyjios>()`
- Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';`
- Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

```
    class StudyjiosList extends StatelessWidget {
      final bool showMine;
      final bool showJoined;

      StudyjiosList(this.showMine, this.showJoined);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final studyjiosData = Provider.of<Studyjios>(context);
        final studyjios = showMine ? studyjiosData.myStudyjios : studyjiosData.items;
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemCount: studyjios.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                create: (ctx) => studyjios[i],
                child : StudyjioItem(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

```
    class Studyjios with ChangeNotifier {
      List<Studyjio> _items = [
        Studyjio(
          id: 's1',
          title: 'CS2040S Finals Revision',
          description: 'We will be going through past year final papers from 2014 to 2018.',
          isOffline: true,
          modules: ['CS2040S'],
          date: DateTime.now(),
          startTime: '2.00pm',
          endTime: '4.00pm',
          capacity: 5,
          bookRoom: true,
          location: 'COM1-0206',
          currentCount: 3,
        ),
        Studyjio(
          id: 's2',
          title: 'CS2030 Practical Exam Timed Practice',
          description: 'We will be doing timed practices for 2017 and 2018 PE papers.',
          isOffline: false, // online session
          modules: ['CS2030'],
          date: DateTime.now(),
          startTime: '1.00pm',
          endTime: '3.00pm',
          capacity: 10,
          bookRoom: false,
          currentCount: 5,
        )
      ]

      List<Studyjio> get items {
        return [..._items];
      }

      List<Studyjio> get myStudyjios {
        return _items.where((studyjioItem) => studyjioItem.isMine).toList();
      }

      Studyjio findbyId(String id) {
        return _items.firstWhere((studyjio) => studyjio.id == id);
      }
```

ps. 'studyjio' means 'study session'

Comment: Have you created a provider for your `Studyjios` class anywhere in your codebase?

Comment: You are trying to use the `Provider.of()` before you finally declare `ChangeNotifierProvider`, so I suggest putting `ChangeNotifierProvider` in a higher widget.

Comment: @GilesCorreiaMorton I don't believe I have, can I ask how do I go about doing that? Thank you!

Comment: @Unbreachable ohh I see..do you have any suggestions on where I should put ChangeNotifierProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you haven't created a provider for `Studyjios` in your widget tree, you have a few options when doing this, and choosing the best one depends on where else you want to be able to use the same provider.

If you will only ever need to use `Provider.of<Studyjios>` inside `StudyjiosList` then you can create the provider inside that class like below:

```dart
class StudyjiosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showMine;
  final bool showJoined;

  StudyjiosList(this.showMine, this.showJoined);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Studyjios>(
      create: (context) => Studyjios(),
      child: buildStudyjios(context),
    );
  }

   Widget buildStudyjios(context) {
        final studyjiosData = Provider.of<Studyjios>(context);
        final studyjios =
            showMine ? studyjiosData.myStudyjios : studyjiosData.items;
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemCount: studyjios.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (ctx) => studyjios[i],
            child: StudyjioItem(),
          ),
        );
      },
}
```

If you want to use `Provider.of<Studyjios>()` or a `Consumer<Studyjios>` (a widget that will listen for changes in `Studyjios`) somewhere else in your app, then you could put the `ChangeNotifierProvider<Studyjios>` higher up in your widget tree so the two places can both use the same provider

In my case I use `MultiProvider` at the very top of my tree and use providers for app wide functionality like `Api` and `Database` services and a `ChangeNotifierProvider` to easily swap between light and dark themes. This way you can be sure that when you need the providers they will be available, you don't need to put them at the top of the tree this is just an example:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProviders(
      providers: [
        Provider(create: (_) => DataBase()),
        Provider(create: (_) => Api()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Theme()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Theme>(
        builder: (context, theme, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'My app',
          theme: theme.light,
          darkTheme: theme.dark,
          themeMode: theme.mode ?? ThemeMode.light,
          ...
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much! However I have a problem keying in the  'builder: ' segment for ChangeNotifierProvider. The error says "'builder' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. will be removed in 4.0.0, use create instead.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement."

Comment: Hey, sorry about that, I’ve updated my answer to use `child` and a function instead of builder.

Comment: thank you so much!! I have updated my code according to your suggestions but I still get the same error :( do you know why that is the case?

Comment: That's strange to get the same error about `builder:`. You could try use a `Consumer< Studyjios>` as the `child:` of the `ChangeNotifierProvider`?

Comment: sorry may I ask how do I go about doing that? thank you so much!! :) @GilesCorreiaMorton